# To kill a Grim Hunter

Tags: cultist-simulator

I'm struggling to find a way to kill a Grim Hunter.

I already tried Dread and Fascination, but that only generates more Dread and Fascination.

Is there a way to get rid of him?

[image]

Comment: I am not sure what exactly you mean with "tried Dread and Fascination". I currently can't access the real names that are used, but killing hunters is possible by sending your minions to kill them (theoretically). Basically by "giving them a job" (using that thing that allows you to perform rituals, but only putting a minion inside at first) and then afterwards when the slot is empty while the minion is "performing their job" putting the hunter card as the subject. There is in general a very low chance that your minions will be able to kill the inspector though. Is this what you mean?

Comment: Yes. Those are called "verbs". The one we are talking about is the "talk" verb. Normally that's how you kill them. One way is to add a minion there and then add the hunter in the subject. You can also poison them. You can also make them go crazy. Psicologic attack is done by adding the hunter first and the "attack" (dread or fascination) on the subject.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just found [this guide](https://www.reddit.com/r/weatherfactory/comments/8ohdsw/a_mostly_comprehensive_guide_to_cultist_simulator/?utm_source=reddit-android) with a huge amount of information regarding the game.

Specifically related to the question, it says

> Use Dread, Fascination, Lantern, or Winter Lore to drive Investigators insane. Grim Hunters are weak to Dread and Winter Lore while Idealists are weak to Fascination and Lantern.

Other ways to kill them :

> Keep murdering/capturing Hunters as they show up by using followers with Edge, or using poisons (items received from Expeditions).

But to accept this answer and close it, I just killed a Grim Hunter AND a Idealist hunter using [Maid-In-The-Mirror](https://cultistsimulator.gamepedia.com/Maid-in-the-Mirror)